# R Shiny: initial rendering of eventReactive output

Tags: r, shiny

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an initial table to be rendered right as the app is executed. But then, update the table only on executing action.

Here's the example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = c("a", "b"), y = c(0,0))

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "inSelect", 
                  label = "Select:", 
                  choices = dt[,unique(x)]), 

      actionButton(inputId = "trigger",
                   label = "Trigger", 
                   icon = icon("refresh"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("outTable")
    )

  )

)



server <- function(input, output){

  re <- eventReactive(input$trigger, {
    dt[x == input$inSelect, y := y + 1]
  })

  output$outTable <- renderTable({
    re()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So the issue is that under `renderTable()` I can put either `dt` to show initial table or `re()` to show each update after first press of the "Trigger" button.

Comment: `ignoreNULL = FALSE` argument for `eventReactive()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
  re <- eventReactive(input$trigger, {
    dt[x == input$inSelect, y := y + 1]
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
```

From `?eventReactive`:

> Both observeEvent and eventReactive take an ignoreNULL parameter that
>   affects behavior when the eventExpr evaluates to NULL (or in the
>   special case of an actionButton, 0).